# How to pass a string as a prop in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am facing a situation where my  component will not render text unless it is rendered as part of ListView. E.g. This one works great:

```
<ListView
  dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
  renderRow={(rowData) =>
    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => navigate('Team', { team: rowData })}
        title={rowData.name}
      />
    </View>
  }
/>
```

But this one does not work, the button does not show any text as if it didn't receive anything

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
    <Button
      onPress={() => navigate('Team')}
      title={'Sample Text'}
    />
  </View>
</View>
```

My Button component return looks like this:

```
return (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={buttonStyle}>
    <Text style={textStyle}>
      {this.props.title}
    </Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
)
```

I put `console.log(this.props.title)` on the render() and the following shows up in the remote debugger console:
`undefined "Sample Text"`

Dependencies in package.json

`"react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "^0.43.4",
    "react-navigation": "git+https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation.git"`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try removing those brackets because you don't need them:
`title='Sample Text'`

Comment: I have tried with and without as in your example but the text is not displayed and I get the same undefined error

Comment: It works for me. If I'm getting the data from rowDate then I do this
`<Button onPress={someFunction} title={rowData.name} />`

If I want to pass a hard coded string then I do this(notice the missing brackets)
`<Button onPress={someFunction} title="Some Text" />`

In the Button component I get the prop the same in both `{this.props.title}`

Comment: I made a test app and found out the error had been in wrongly configured styling with flexbox and it's children components which prevented the text from showing up correctly

Comment: Tried to pass like `functionName(title) {}` and tried to use `<Text>{title}</Text>` - it shows a mistake "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Change argument to props, like this `functionName(props) {}` and changed using to `<Text>{props.title}</Text>` - that works fine.

Maybe it will be helpful for someone.